# balance pre-length and post-length

Tags: decorations, pgf-decorations

In [Can TikZ dashed lines emulate PSTricks dashed lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133271/), @Dominic asked if one can balance the dash pattern so that an ant living on the curve cannot distinguish the two ends.

Same problem arise naturally in PGF/Ti*k*Z decorations, for example

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\tikz[decoration={snake,pre length=2mm,post length=2mm,segment length=4mm}]
    \draw[<->,decorate](0,0)--(2,0);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that 2cm = 2mm + 2mm + 4mm*4, so the decoration should be *exact*. But even so I did not get a balanced decoration.

The general question is

> Given `pre length`=`post length` and `segment length`, can one manipulate the underlying mechanism so that the *de facto* pre-length and post-length coincide?

P.S. the library calculates the total length of the curve for you.

Comment: It looks like the first little bend of path, i.e. the transition from the horizontal path to the decoration, is not accounted for. See for example this code: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/66cbd722d24af191b48f34657e66b4ef I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: I guess you have discovered by now that TikZ has a *switch off if distance left is less than <...>* directive active for these. You can use Jake's https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60733/3235 if you want

Comment: @percusse If I recall correctly, that option works pretty much like `\foreach\i in{5,10,...,33}` so the final length is not `33` but an awkward number `30`. Thus we still have to do the pathetic computation...