# Decorate a multi-segment path without changing segment endpoints

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tikz-path

I'd like to draw multi-segment "wavy" paths, so I tried both the standard `snake` decoration, and the very promising [`complete sines`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60757/2113) one as well, but in both cases, the segment endpoints are not kept.

Here's an illustration of what I mean. The first rectangle is drawn from single-segment paths, and look great (especially the `complete sines` one at the bottom). However, when drawing two segments, or a whole rectangle, in one go, the wavy segments don't end at the intended segment endpoints.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\input{sine.tex} %% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60757/2113

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset
      { wavy/.style={red, decorate, sharp corners, decoration={snake, amplitude=0.4mm}}
      , siny/.style={blue, decorate, sharp corners, decoration={complete sines, amplitude=1mm}}
      }

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)}]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);
    \draw[#1] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);
    
    \draw (1,0) -- ++ (0,1);
    \draw[#1] (1,0) -- ++ (0,1);
    
    \draw (1,1) -- ++ (-1,0);
    \draw[#1] (1,1) -- ++(-1,0);
    
    \draw (0,1) -- (0,0);
    \draw[#1] (0,1) -- (0,0);
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++ (1,0) -- ++ (0,1);
    \draw[#1] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0) -- ++ (0,1);
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    \draw[#1] (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)}]
  \test{wavy}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2)}]
  \test{siny}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to get results matching the first column? I'd like to clip by these paths so I think I need to draw them as one multi-segment path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for `snake`, it seems to work if I break down the segments into their own `decorate{}` block:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\segmentrect}[3]{
  decorate{ #1 -- ++ (#2,0) }
  decorate{ -- ++ (0,#3) }
  decorate{ -- ++ ({-(#2)},0) }
  decorate{ -- cycle }
}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
\draw[decoration={snake, amplitude=0.4mm,segment length=2mm},red]
  \segmentrect{(0,0)}{1}{1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the same approach for `complete sines` results in complete disaster:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\input{sine.tex} %% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60757/2113

\newcommand{\segmentrect}[3]{
  decorate{ #1 -- ++ (#2,0) }
  decorate{ -- ++ (0,#3) }
  decorate{ -- ++ ({-(#2)},0) }
  decorate{ -- cycle }
}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
\draw[decoration={complete sines},blue]
  \segmentrect{(0,0)}{1}{1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. The snake only ends in a wave node at the ends of the decoration, so to enforce nodes at the corners, you simply decorate each line separately. Always post complete compilable code.

Comment: @hpekristiansen you meanI should replicate everything outside the `begin{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: You should(like OP) post code that starts with `\documentclass...` and ends with `\end{document}`. That way OP and others can copy+paste your code directly and see/modify you findings.

Comment: @hpekristiansen but doctor, I am Pagliacci^WOP