# Pure sine decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf

Tikz offers `snake` decoration, which is however not pure sine decoration.  As written in Tikz manual, `snake` is "sine wave with a softened start and ending".  I would like to have pure sine decoration.

I am aware that there is a solution for `complete sines`, which always draws full number of sines:

[TikZ finishes a morphed path with a straight segment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29639/tikz-finishes-a-morphed-path-with-a-straight-segment)

The problem is that I want that line gets straight if sines do not fit in.  Ie.

```
\draw [decoration={sines,segment length=1cm,amplitude=1cm},decorate] (0,0) -- (0,1.6cm);
```

should draw 1.5 sines and straight line 0.1cm long.  It should also work with `pre length` and `post length`, just as `snake` does.

I guess this should be simpler that `complete sines`, but I don't know how to tweak @Jake's solution to my needs.

Comment: Does the post [tikz-decorated-paths-without-straight-segment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60733/tikz-decorated-paths-without-straight-segment/60757#60757) answer your question?

Comment: @Andrew no.  I want to have possibility of straight segment in the beginning and/or in the end of the decoration.  `start up` and `start down` is nice feature, though :)

Comment: I don't see any reason this should be closed. It seems sufficiently clear and not solved. An MWE would be nice, so the question could certainly be improved. But I don't think that's sufficient to close it, is it?