# chemfig, how to do these wavy markings?

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to reproduce this:

[image]

So far I have:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{*5(5-1-2(-((-[:90,1,,,decorate,decoration=snake])-[:-90,1,,,decorate,decoration=snake]))-3-4*6(-6-7-8-9-5-)-)}

\end{document}
```

But the wavy line really doesn't look very good. Can someone think of a better way of doing that? Also, looking at the number 5 there is something strange going on there. What's wrong with that?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to use the decoration `complete sines` from [Nicer wavy line with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25689/) as I've used [in a blog post of mine a while ago](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2012/03/wavy-bonds/):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[
    width=+0pt,
    next state=sine,
    persistent precomputation={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
        \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength /
        int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)
      }
      \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
    }]{}
  \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
      \pgfpathsine{
        \pgfpoint
          {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
          {0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
      \pgfpathcosine{
        \pgfpoint
          {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
          {-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
      \pgfpathsine{
        \pgfpoint
          {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
          {-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
      \pgfpathcosine{
        \pgfpoint
          {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
          {0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
  }
  \state{final}{}
}

\tikzset{wv/.style={decorate,decoration=complete sines}}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{*5(5-1-2(-((-[:90,1,,,wv])-[:-90,1,,,wv]))-3-4*6(-6-7-8-9-5-))}

\end{document}
```

For reproducing the picture I'd probably also define a submol:

```
\tikzset{wv/.style={decorate,decoration=complete sines}}
\definesubmol{R}{-[,.5]((-[::90,.5,,,wv])-[::-90,.5,,,wv])}
```

and then:

```
\chemfig{*5(9-1-2(!R)-3(!R)-4*6(-5-6-7-8-9-))}
```

[image]

For more customization of the wavy bond you might be interested in this blog post by Joseph Wright: [Exploring ChemFig: Going further](http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/26/exploring-chemfig-going-further/)

Comment: This is a very helpful and the code provided works well. However, if you decrease the atom seperation below 20 pt (i.e. using \setchemfig{atom sep=19pt}), pgf throws a division by zero error. I assume this is connected to the complete sines declaration, but I do not have the skill to fix it. Any idea, how the code could be amended to also work with more ACS style like chemfig structures?