# How to draw the wavy line meaning that part of a molecule has been omitted, in chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

[EDIT] I've just found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260884/chemfig-how-to-do-these-wavy-markings/260887#260887), but I'm working on it because I'd like the wavy line to be separated from the bond.

---

I'm trying to write this reaction scheme:

[image]

I had defined a macro for the wavy line under the NADH and NAD+, which takes its inclination as argument:

```
\newcommand*{\wavyline}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=\bondwidth]
                               \draw [decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.3mm,segment length=1.3mm}] (0,0) -- (#1:0.67);
                           \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Now I've just tried to use it and the output is this:

[image]

How can I bring it closer to the bond? I think I need to "reduce the margins" around the Tikz picture, but I don't know how.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcommand*{\wavyline}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
                               \draw [decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.3mm,segment length=1.3mm}] (0,0) -- (#1:0.67);
                           \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-N(-[:-90]\wavyline{0})-=(-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]N|\ce{H2})--=-)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For a separation insert a short invisible bond `-[,.2,,,draw=none]` (change `.2` to a value you like)