# Chemical equation with radiation arrow

Tags: equations, symbols, mhchem

I would like to to write the following equation in my document in latex. [image: Gamma radiation chemical equation]

I am using `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}`. How can I write that in latex to get a similar outcome? (The arrow can be shorter but has to be a "wave").
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is easy with `mhchem` (but I may be mistaken…)

The following try uses the `chemformula` package instead of `mhchem` and uses TikZ/pgf and [Jake's `complete sines` decoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25689) for the wavy line. `chemformula` allows to define new arrows for the usage in chemical reactions. Since the syntax differs in significant details from `mhchem`'s this may or may not be a viable solution for you.

As a shortcut for the usage I define a style

```
\tikzset{
  wave/.style={
    decorate,decoration={
      complete sines,
      segment length=3pt,
      amplitude=2pt
    }
  }
}
```

Now I load the [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) package and define a new arrow:

```
\NewChemArrow{w>}{
  \path (cf_arrow_end) -- +(-5pt,0) coordinate (xxx) ; 
  \draw[chemarrow,wave] (cf_arrow_start) -- (xxx) ;
   \draw[chemarrow,-cf] (xxx) -- (cf_arrow_end);
}
```

Now this can be used just like any other of `chemformula`'s arrows:

```
\ch{P w>[$\gamma$-radiation] P^*}
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula,tikz}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25689
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[
    width = +0pt ,
    next state = sine,
    persistent precomputation = {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
        \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength /
        int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)
      }
      \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
    }
  ]{}
  \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
    \pgfpathsine{
      \pgfpoint
        {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
        {0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
    \pgfpathcosine{
      \pgfpoint
        {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
        {-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
    \pgfpathsine{
      \pgfpoint
        {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
        {-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
    \pgfpathcosine{
      \pgfpoint
        {0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
        {0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
  }
  \state{final}{}
}

% a shortcut to use the new decoration:
\tikzset{
  wave/.style={
    decorate,decoration={
      complete sines,
      segment length=3pt,
      amplitude=2pt
    }
  }
}

% a new arrow:
\NewChemArrow{w>}{
  \path (cf_arrow_end) -- +(-5pt,0) coordinate (xxx) ; 
  \draw[chemarrow,wave] (cf_arrow_start) -- (xxx) ;
   \draw[chemarrow,-cf] (xxx) -- (cf_arrow_end);
}

\begin{document}

\ch{P w> P^*}

\ch{P w>[$\gamma$-radiation] P^*}

\end{document}
```