# Replace the zigzag decoration by wave decoration in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, decorations

First of all, I would like to thank CarLateX for her answer in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493654/reproduce-the-vertical-margins-below-the-environment).

My request is to replace the zigzag decoration with a wave decoration in this code

```
\tcolorboxenvironment{defin}{
blanker,
breakable,
before skip=\topsep,
after skip=\topsep,
borderline west={1pt}{20pt}{decoration={**zigzag**,amplitude=2pt,pre=moveto,pre 
length=12pt},decorate}
}
```

where wave is like the following image
[image]

Thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Apart from [CarLaTeX's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493654/reproduce-the-vertical-margins-below-the-environment), from which I copy also the MWE, this code use [Jake's complete sines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25689/121799) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485391/121799), where more details and explanations can be found.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremindent40pt 
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[
        width=+0pt,
        next state=sine,
        persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
            \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength / int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)}
            \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
        }] {}
    \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
}
    \state{final}{}
}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{defin}{
    blanker,
    breakable,
    before skip=\topsep,
    after skip=\topsep,
     overlay={%
     \draw[fill,decoration={complete sines,segment length=9.5pt,path has corners}]
      decorate{ ([xshift=20pt,yshift=1.5pt]frame.south west) 
        -- ([xshift=20pt,yshift=-12pt]frame.north west)} -- 
         ([xshift=21.5pt,yshift=-13.5pt]frame.north west)
      decorate{([xshift=21.5pt,yshift=-13.5pt]frame.north west) --
      ([xshift=21.5pt,yshift=0pt]frame.south west)}  -- ([xshift=20pt,yshift=1pt]frame.south west)  
        ;
    },
    }

\begin{document}


\section{My section}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{defin}
\lipsum[4]
\end{defin}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nice, +1! Just a silly question --- it seems that at the end you are not using the `oldfashioned sines` definition, or am I blind?

Comment: @Rmano Thanks. Yes, you are right. I changed gears and filled the region between the complete sines instead of drawing two or several shifted copies.

Comment: @Rmano Slight correction: it did actually use the parameters and keys of that style, but the actual style was not used, as you say. Thanks! I edited accordingly.