# How to save the current color in PGF/TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

In TikZ/PGF, we can obtain the current line width using `\pgflinewidth`. Unfortunatelly there is no (as far as I know) `\pgfstrokecolor`, `\pgffillcolor`, `\pgfstrokeopacity` and `\pgffillopacity`.

> My main question is : Is there some way to recover the current draw and fill color ?

I know that the last color set by `\color` [can be recovered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218091/9335) with `\colorlet{saved}{.}`, because dot represent the last color. And this can be used when we directly set the color as a style, like in `\draw[red] ...` (see the code).

I've tried to hack `\pgfsetstrokecolor`, `\pgfsetfillcolor` and `\pgfsetcolor` in a way to save the last call ... but without success.

In the following code I'm looking for some trick to save the colors in a way to be able to reuse them in another layer.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[green, draw=red, ultra thick, fill=yellow, text=purple]
    \filldraw (-.5,-.5) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{A};
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\savedpgflinewidth}{\pgflinewidth}
    \colorlet{saved}{.}
    \def\pgfstrokecolor{red} % <- to be replaced by \strokecolorlet
    \def\pgffillcolor{yellow} % <- to be replaced by \fillcolorlet

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
      \draw (0,0) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{B};
      \color{saved} % <- restore the color set by \color{green}
      \pgfsetlinewidth{\savedpgflinewidth} % <- restore the line width
      \draw (.5,.5) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{C};
      \pgfsetstrokecolor{\pgfstrokecolor} % <- restore the draw color
      \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgffillcolor} % <- restore the fill color
      \filldraw (1,1) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{D};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \filldraw (1.5,1.5) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{E}; % <- line width reset after pgfonlayer !
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note 1:** In the following code we can see that the line width is reset after the use of `pgfonlayer`. Is this a bug or a (documented) feature ?

**Note 2:** In a strange way the text color survive the layer change, but not the other colors, neither the line width.

**Note 3:** I have the impression that `\pgfsetcolor` is not used by TikZ, instead `\color` is used. If this is the case, why ?

---

**EDIT** : The code above is just a working example. I don't want to solve this particular case without recovering the colors.

Comment: The simple way is the declarative way: use `pgfkeys` and  its `.style` handler to store your preferences (color, line width, etc.) and to apply them multiple times.

Comment: The reason why you can't have this in the high-level form is because red is ambiguous depending on the color model etc. also colormixins make it more difficult but if you are happy with low level you can read of the softer versions from `\color@pgfstrokecolor`

Comment: @percusse this looks very promising ! Could you make an answer please. I've tried without success. I came to look at `pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex` and it is used always inside a long long sequence of `\expandafter` that I can't understand ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a conceptual way of doing it. I think there are a lot of things to improve (less macros because you only need the last two items in the color description, proper expansion control, possibility of custom macro name) but I didn't have time. I think you can take it from here.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{get stroke color/.code={%
    \expandafter\global% Jump over, now we have \global
    \expandafter\let% Jump over now we have \global\let
    \expandafter\pgfsavedstrokecolor% Jump we have \global\let\pgf...
    \csname\string\color@pgfstrokecolor\endcsname% Finally expand this and put it at the end 
    },                                           % \global\let\pgf...{} in expanded form 
    restore stroke color/.code={\pgf@setstrokecolor#1},
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[green, draw=yellow!20!blue, ultra thick, fill=yellow, text=purple]
    \tikzset{get stroke color}% <-- Gets the drive-dependent low-level desc of y!20!b
    \show\pgfsavedstrokecolor% <-- Look at the log
    \filldraw (0,0) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{A};
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{orange} % <-- Change the drawing color to orange
    \draw (0.5,0.5) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{B}; % <-- Draw something to verify
    \tikzset{restore stroke color/.expand once=\pgfsavedstrokecolor} % <-- Restore it back
    \draw (1,1) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{C}; % <-- Verify
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is fantastic. I have some questions : 1) in the same way I can use `\color@pgffillcolor`, but I can't find the equivalent values for opacity. Have you an idea ? 2) In the code of my quastion if I put `\tikzset{get stroke color}` as first line, it works fine, but if I put it after the `\filldraw` it doesn't work. Any Idea ? 3) [not important] Why we can't use directly `\color@pgfstrokecolor` ?

Comment: @Kpym Bah, I knew it was to good to be true off-the-shelf. I'll check again.

Comment: If I use `\tikz@options` just before `\tikzset{get stroke color}` it works. But I can't use it anywhere (for example in `pic`).

Comment: @Kpym I've checked a bit again. If you give the option `get stroke color` to `\filldraw` it works again for your question 2. So that means we have to be in the same scope as the path commands. Can you try if there are other weirdnesses?

Comment: Thanks again! For the moment it looks ok for me. If I find another drawback, I'll be back here ;)

Comment: I spoke too fast :( It works like before : if I put `get stroke color` in the first `filldraw` it is ok, but if I use it later, it doesn't work for me. But thanks again to investigating my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is the declarative way: use `pgfkeys` and its `.style` handler to store your preferences (color, line width, etc.) and to apply them multiple times.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{my preferecences/.style={green, draw=red, ultra thick,fill=yellow, text=purple}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my preferecences]
    \filldraw (-.5,-.5) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{A};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
      \begin{scope}[my preferecences]
      \draw (0,0) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{B};
      \draw (.5,.5) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{C};
      \filldraw (1,1) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{D};
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \filldraw (1.5,1.5) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway]{E}; % <- line width reset after pgfonlayer !
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not my question. I know how to use styles. This is a simple working example. I want to know if I can recover the current color. I want to define a style that can be used in any path by recovering the color and drawing something on another layer.

Comment: I came to edit my question to precise that I don't want a solution without 'traversing' the color from one layer to another. Sorry if my question was not clear.